# Why does the pre/absence of xargs affect the output from a subsequent echo command?

Tags: bash, shell

Bash noob here, curious in the behavior of the following shell function (designed to quickly pack ascifiied hex sequences):

```
pack()
{
    sedF=$(Extended_SED)               # choose "-r"/"-E" for BSD/Linux flavors
    IN=$(sed 's/%//g' <<< "$1")        # allow "%41%41..."
    if [ -z $(grep '\\x' <<< "$IN") ]  # allow "4142..."
    then 
        IN=$(sed -$sedF 's/(..)/\\\\x\1/g' <<< "$IN")
    else                               # allow "\x41\x42..."
        IN=$(sed -$sedF 's/\\/\\\\/g' <<< "$IN")
    fi
    echo "$IN" | xargs echo -en        # pack through -e, suppress CR
   # testing
    echo "$IN"                     
    echo -en "$IN"                     # doesn't pack
 }
```

Both `pack "\x41\x41"` and `pack "4141"` produce the following output:

```
AA\\x41\\x41
\x41\x41
```

But when I run `echo -e "\\x41\\x41"` or `echo -e "\x41\x41"` from the command line, outside the script, I always get `AA`, which is puzzlingly different from the behavior of these commands when run inside the script.

So even though it's not a problem for the script, I am curious - (a) why, inside the script, is only the use of `xargs` leading to the desired output by `echo -en`? ; and (b) why does the behavior of non-`xargs` `echo` inside the script differ from that outside the script, i.e. when run from the command line?

Comment: Outside the script, your command-line shell may not be bash.  What does "echo $SHELL" say, for instance?

Comment: `$SHELL` is `/bin/bash`

Comment: `xargs echo` will execute the external command `echo`, very likely at `/bin/echo`, and this is not your builtin `echo`. Try (from your  command line) with your external echo: `/bin/echo -e '\x41\x41'`… [POSIX specifies that the `echo` utility doesn't take any options](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - wow, I didn't realize that something as simple as `echo` had so many portability problems.  I'll try to rewrite using `printf` to avoid the annoying inconsistency.  Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: As an aside, I don't see anything in there which couldn't be done natively in Bash.  Spawning a horde of `sed` processes to parse a single string seems awfully inefficient, inelegant, and misdirected.  If you really do require something beyond basic Bash, I would urge you to seriously consider Awk (or Perl, or Python, or Ruby) for this.  `IN=${1//%/}; case $IN in *'\\x'*) ...`

Comment: why would using awk / perl / python be preferable to using `sed`?  two lines (considerably shorter than the snippet above) of `sed` deal with every format I need to be worried with, though the `IN=${1//%/};` construction is a new one to me so thanks for sharing that.

Comment: BTW I think you mean `case $IN in *'\x'*)`

Comment: OK sweet.  read up on the manual this morning and got it down to one `sed` line.  It does seem a bit faster now. Thank you for pointing me towards new information!